# How can I pass a user inputted value into the request parameter body in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, api, post

I am working with an API. I am developing a Windows Form using C#.

The API developers request that for use of their API the request body contains a string like this (which I have tested in PostMan)

```
{"registrationNumber": "YC58 UHZ"}
```

The working example given looks like this

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"registrationNumber\":\"YC58UHZ\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I wish to pass an input value into the 'YC58UHZ' value part e.g. from a textbox txtInputtedReg.Text

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"registrationNumber\":\"{txtInputtedReg.Text}\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Q1) How can I pass a string value into the inline formatting?
Q2) How can I pass a quotation mark into a string in C#?

Comment: for Q1 take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated, generally i would recomand you work through some basic c# tutorials, there they explain how to escape strings, interplation and so on

Comment: You are right. I fixed it with interpolated string.

Answer (score 0):

Interpolated string - passed the value in whilst keeping the required API format

```cs
request.AddParameter("application/json",
    $"{{\n\t\"registrationNumber\":\"{txtInputtedReg.Text}\"\n}}",
    ParameterType.RequestBody);
```